How to anchor post base on uneven slab to prevent rot
I am replacing some posts for a garage overhang and carport that were sitting directly on concrete. The posts are probably over 60 years old but since they were sat directly on concrete, they rotted at the bottom. Some in much worse condition than others.
One of the challenges is that the concrete slab they sit on is slanted for drainage.
Trying to figure out the best way to attach posts to concrete so they don't rot at the bottom again.
I was thinking of using simpsom zmax anchor base with 1 inch standoffs but not sure if I should shim to level it
Also thought about forming a concrete base that is a few inches off the ground for the posts to sit on so its level and then adding anchor base but not sure if its needed and prob wont look as good.
Any recommendations for the best way to do this would be appreciated. Posts in picture are round 8 inch diameter posts and I will be replacing with 8x8 rough sawn square lumber.


The second image is the worst one and had another roof draining on it on one side. That part of the slab is most uneven for drainage.
The

You could probably save a bunch of money by determining how far up the rot goes, building plinths to support post bases slightly higher than that, and not replacing the posts, just support each and cut off the base to sound timber (probably all to whatever the highest point of rot is for consistency) and put the plinth under it, mount to the post base, and move the supports to the next one; repeating until done.

Thanks, I've been thinking about that. The really bad one actually had another roof draining onto one side so its completely shot and so I am planning to relocate that a few inches to the left and put a gutter in.
Haven't been able to find anchors for the round posts though, I could probably make something though.

Considering it's sitting on a drainage slab I would dip the base in copper naphthenate to prevent rot regardless of which method of anchoring/isolation you decide to use, even with a 1" standoff.
As far as the base anchor, I think you have the right idea.  If the slope isn't too large, shim it. Several of the Simpson brand heavy-duty anchors used to come with stainless steel shims, but I'm sure that's long gone as a cost cutter.  If shims are unreasonable as is, I'd personally go with ablating the concrete to a level surface where the anchor is going.  If you go that route, the copper naphthenate mentioned above is definitely important.

Thanks this is helpful. I can't seem to find the stainless steel shims, but I will keep looking. I think I read somewhere they make heady duty plastic shims as well but haven't found them yet.
